# Do I have to convert this tuple to a list before I turn it into a int?

Tags: python, int, pygame, tuples

I am new to programming. I am trying to convert the highest resolution that pygame detects is available into a integer but I was recieving errors when I tried converting a tuple into a int.

I understand I can't change a tuple, but I was making a new int and it wouldn't accept the tuple value.

So I finally got around that error by converting the tuple to a list first like this.

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

modes = pygame.display.list_modes()
maxWindow = list(modes[0])
WINDOWWIDTH = int(maxWindow[0])
WINDOWHEIGHT = int(maxWindow[1])
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this conversion? I'm guessing I'm taking the long way around.

Also, is there a pygame function that will auto-detect max or native resolution for me and this code is unnecessary?

Thanks

Comment: Why split it at all? `pygame.display.set_mode(maxWindow, pygame.FULLSCREEN)`

Comment: That's probably my bad for not putting in more of the program, but the answer is because of pygame.Rect objects that use them seperately later like this. pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - 20), random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - 20), 40, 100)

Comment: Oh, ok. Then just use `WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT = modes[0]`. This should work because `list_modes()` already returns two-tuples of integers, no need to cast width / height to integers, you only need to unpack the tuple.

Comment: Thanks, this works and seems better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `map` function:

```
WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT = map(int, modes[0])
```

As @LukasGraf mentioned, `pygame.display.list_modes()` returns a list of tuples that **contains integers**, therefore, **mapping to int** is unnecessary. Instead, you can just do this:

```
WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT = modes[0]
```

Comment: I've never used the map function before. I don't think inventwithpython or codecademy covered it but I tossed it in there and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: It's entirely [unnecessary](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#comment_pygame_display_list_modes) though.

Comment: I'm not used to pygame. Thanks for pointing it out @LukasGraf. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Christian's answer does what you need. Also you can learn about [list comprehensions](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) which give a generic structure to mapping, filtering, etc. Using list comprehensions you can do the same via:

```
WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = [int(x) for x in modes[0]]
```

Comment: That list comprehension will work, but is entirely unnecessary. `list_modes()` already [returns a list of two-tuples of integers](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#comment_pygame_display_list_modes).

Comment: Didn't see your comment on the original question. Yea if we are already getting tuples then no need to go through it again.